# How to lower the quality of file input images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I'm using this code:

```
<form id="file-form" method="POST">
<input type="file" onchange="openFile(event)" 
 id="file-select" capture="camera">
<br>
<img id="output">
</form>
```

And when called from mobile iOS i get this:

[image]

If i choose a existing image its usually around 200kb in size. However if i take a new photo instead of choosing existing it's always around 1.50MB.

I get the image file like this

```
 var data = new FormData(); 
 var files = $("#file-select").get(0).files;
 data.append('imgfile', files[0]);
```

and send as form data with ajax  and to a ASP.NET Web api which saves the images in a azure blob storage container.

Question is, what can/should i do to be able to lower the size of the images that are taken directly and not choosen from existing library?

Any help or input highly appreciated, thanks!